# How to see more detailed graph in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How do I make the Graph in x and y axis display every 1 value like in x axis I want the graph to display 1 2 3 4 etc

[image: This is the view() function]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast and simple can be:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(1,25)) # for x-axis
plt.yticks(np.arange(1,25)) # for y-axis
```